# Is there any way to round textfile.write to 2 decimal places?

Tags: python

So I need to output a txt file that in one row contains the city-value of all companies in said industry rounded on 2 decimal places. Code works as intended I just need to round them to 2 decimal places. I have some guess in what seems to be problem with rounding them but i just cant figure it out

```
import os

try:
   import pandas as pd
except ImportError:
     os.system("pip install pandas")


def main(filename='statups.csv'):
    # reading the csv
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)

    # grouping by industry name and city and summing the value
    ast = df.groupby(['Industry', 'City'], as_index=False)['Valuation 
    ($B)'].sum()
    # sorting the columns
    ast = ast.sort_values(by=['Industry', 'Valuation ($B)'], ascending= 
    [True, False])

# could have done with pandas but ran into saving group by to csv function error
# and went with inefficient way

   # creating the dictionary to hold each industry value
   my_dict = {}
   for val in ast['Industry'].unique():
       val = val.replace(" ", '_')
       my_dict[val] = []

   # storing the value in dictionary
   for index, row in ast.iterrows():
       val = row['Industry'].replace(" ", '_')
       my_dict[val].append(str(row['City']) + "-" + str(row['Valuation 
       ($B)']))

   # saving the value from the dictionary
   for k in my_dict.keys():
       with open(f'{k} + ".txt", 'w') as textfile:
           for element in my_dict[k]:
              textfile.write('{:0.3f}'.format(element) + "\n")         
if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = input('Enter filename: ')
    main(filename)
```

Comment: What type of object is *element*?

Comment: Simply round(element,2). That is if element is a number, if not, cast it to double

Comment: @sagi There is no *double* type in Python

Comment: So the equivalent float..

Comment: @sagi I didn't think the concept of *cast* existed in Python (unlike, for example, Java)

Comment: You stick to the words too much, the idea I suggested is clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241041/discussion-between-jcaesar-and-sagi).

Answer (score 3):

f-string formatting in Python will do the rounding for you. Therefore you could do it like this:

```
for k, v in my_dict.items():
  with open(f'{k}.txt', 'w') as textfile:
    for v_ in v:
      textfile.write(f'{float(v_):.2f}\n')
```

This will fail if v_ cannot be converted to float

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions based on the edited question?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to format values. One possibility is to use the `str.format()` method (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format for details).

Based on your code and assuming the dictionary values are lists of numbers:

```
my_dict = { "a": [3.17213], "b": [3.98992] } # or similar

for k in my_dict.keys():
    with open(k + ".txt", 'w') as textfile:
        for element in my_dict[k]:
           textfile.write('{:0.3f}'.format(element) + "\n") # write with a precision of 3 digits after the decimal point
```

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions based on the edited question?

Answer (score -1):

So I found a solution, I just needed to change

```
my_dict[val].append(str(row['City']) + "-" + str(row['Valuation ($B)']))
```

To

```
my_dict[val].append(str(row['City']) + "-" + str('{:.2f}'.format(row['Valuation ($B)'])))`
```